# Manual filter for email. Javascript

Tags: javascript, email, filter, email-validation

I'm a newbie in javascript and stuff. I got this filter through browsing.

It says:

```
function checkemail(emailtotest) {
    var testemail;
    var filter = /^([\w-\'\+]+(?:\.[\w-\'\+]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    if (filter.test(emailtotest)) {
        testemail = true;
    }
    else {
        testemail = false;
    }
    return (testemail);
}
```

Something I'd like to ask, and wish to understand is, what does "/^([\w-\'+]+(?:.[\w-\'+]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+.)*\w[\w-]{0,66}).([a-z]{2,6}(?:.[a-z]{2})?)$/i" mean?

Is there any javascript guru willing to help this newbie?

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`/some-magical-stuff/[modifiers]` is syntax for a [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). An alternative syntax is `new RegExp("some-magical-stuff", "[modifiers]")`. It's functionally equivalent. As for what the regular expression means, that's not too hard to figure out once you learn Regular Expressions.

Comment: Thanks heaps! I better go reading the link which you just gave. @frits